# @ConfigurationProperties в тестировании бросают NullPointer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, springbatch

Пишу интеграционный тест для Spring Batch - в качестве тестовых ресурсов (*.csv) решила написать отдельный конфиг. Вот, как то выглядит:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "resources")
@Data
@TestConfiguration
public class ResourcesTestConfig {
    private Resource first;
    private Resource second;
}
```

```
//appliication.yml
resources:
  first: classpath:first.csv
  second: classpath:second.csv
```

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Slf4j
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class SpringBatchApplicationIntegrationTest {
    @Autowired
    private ResourcesTestConfig resourcesConfig;

    @Test
    public void someTest() {... }
}
```

На этом все. ResourcesTestConfig = null.

Из того, что я пыталась сделать:

Заменяла `@TestConfiguration` на `@Configuration` или `@Component`, и убирала вовсе. Дописывала к `@EnableConfigurationProperties(classes ... my resourcesconfig class)`, пыталась так же импортировать его аннотацией `@Import`. Использовала `@ContextConfiguration(classes... )`

К сожалению, не сработало. Как это можно поправить?

Стектрейс:

```
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, в тестах добавьте аннотации:


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Import(ResourcesTestConfig.class)

Comment: Нельзя) SpringRunner для junit4 - я использую junit5, и аннотация @SpringBootTest автоматически включает @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)

Comment: Мой косяк! Не думала, что Intellij использует для запусков тестов и junit4, и junit5. Сейчас все работает, спасибо! Конечно же, я попробовала добавить @RunWith, никто же не умрет, и не зря) MaksimDrobyshev , отправьте пожалуйста это в виде ответа, ткну галочку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте в тестовый класс аннотации:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Import(ResourcesTestConfig.class)
```